# what is the different between 'new()' int and 'int *p'

Tags: c++

As the following codes:

```
int *p;
*p = 10;
int *q = new() int(10);
```

I want to know the differences between `p` and `q`. Can `int *q = new() int(10)` be replaced by `int *q; *q = 10` anywhere?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `int *p;` is uninitialized, hence `*p = 10;` is undefined behavior.

Comment: I guess yes, because you have already invoked *undefined behavior* and the new code won't emit compile error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. They are far from the same.

This:

> int *p;
>      *p = 10;

Declares a (uninitialized) pointer to int named `p`. Then assignes the value `10` to what `p` points to.
This is " undefined behaviour" since `p` is uninitialized.

This:

> int *q = new() int(10);

Declares a int pointer `q` and initializes it to point to the storage allocated by `new` which has allocated space for 10 int's (if we disregard the syntactically incorrect "()" after new).

To summarize: both - as written - are invalid, broken code, but not the same.

Note: `new(...)` is "placement new" which is not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int *p;
> *p = 10;
> ```

Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer has undefined behaviour.

> ```
> int *q = new() int(10);
> ```

This is syntactically incorrect, as the following compiler message reveals:

> ```
> main.cpp:7:18: error: expected expression-list or type-id
>      int *q = new() int(10);
>                   ^
> ```

So, to answer the question...

> Can `int *q = new() int(10)` be replaced by `int *q; *q = 10` anywhere?

No. Neither may be used anywhere in a program.

Comment: `int *q = new() int(10); std::cout << *q`is correct in my computer, I am using linux.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p
```

This defines the pointer p. As it is not initialized, p is pointing to an unknown memory location.

```
*p = 10;
```

This is trying to set the memory location to 10. As the memory location is unknown, this leads to undefined behavior.

Correct code for initializing q to 10 is

```
int *q = new int;
```

This allocates memory space for int and then q is made to point to this memory location.

```
*q = 10;
```

This initializes this memory location to 10.